# Issue with SVG Scale in android

Tags: android, android-layout

I am trying to add a SVG to my layout but the problem is side padding and top padding. I want my svg to start from the top without any padding and no padding on the left and side as well.

Below is my layout code XML looks like

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/overview_image"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:contentDescription="image"
        android:scaleType="centerInside"
        android:src="@drawable/path" />
</LinearLayout>
```

And my SVG code

```
<vector android:height="160dp"
    android:viewportHeight="433.154"
    android:viewportWidth="1260"
    android:width="500dp"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">


  <path android:fillColor="#803ef6"
        android:pathData="M90,149.52c22.6,-54.47 52.2,-81.02 85.31,-68.8s397.97,176.79 648.32,226.77c87.62,17.49 156.34,-7.58 208.53,-47.46C1129.43,185.68 1170,60 1170,60L90,60Z"/>
</vector>
```

I have tried all option in the android:scaleType but not able to achieve what I want.

[image]

Below Design is what I want to achieve.

[image: Image2]

**SVG is made in adobe XD.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Make these changes:**

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/lin"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/overview_image"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:contentDescription="image"
        android:scaleX="1.20"
        android:scaleY="1.40"
        android:background="@drawable/ic_launcher_background" />

    </RelativeLayout>


</RelativeLayout>
```

**Vector SVG file:**

```
<vector android:height="160dp"
    android:viewportHeight="433.154"
    android:viewportWidth="1275"
    android:width="500dp"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <path android:fillColor="#803ef6"
        android:pathData="M90,149.52c22.6,-54.47 52.2,-81.02 85.31,-68.8s397.97,176.79 648.32,226.77c87.62,17.49 156.34,-7.58 208.53,-47.46C1129.43,185.68 1170,60 1170,60L90,60Z"/>
</vector>
```

[image]